# UIViewController navigation - Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted

Tags: uiviewcontroller, pushviewcontroller, popviewcontroller

In my app I use navigation controller to traverse between various viewcontrollers. I have view controllers A,B,C,D and E. I use push and pop to go back and forth. The issue is when the app is launched, I am able to traverse through the view controllers without any  issues.

Before every push and pop  I NSLog the view controller stack and it is as good as expected.  But when I come to the root view controller again and start the navigation again, I am getting "nested push animation can result in corrupted navigation bar"
Even before the error when I NSLog the stack, the stack has no issues and is as expected. Then I get the error "Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted."

What is surprising is I am not able to debug because I am clueless where the error is coming from as NSLog of viewcontroller stack is fine. Kindly help me.

Comment: To add to this, upon further investigation, this happens at the fifth UIViewcontroller push. when I NSLog before button click, I get A,B,C,D and after button click I get A,B,C,D,E in the UIViewcontroller stack. But strangely E is not visible. Kindly help me.

Answer (score 0):

This article help me - http://keighl.com/post/ios7-interactive-pop-gesture-custom-back-button/

I just override UINavigationController.